# How to read a CNF file?

Tags: cnf

i'm working on argumentation system made by Dung
how to read this file content?
it's a cnf file describe an  abstract argumentation framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCv6F.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Looks like [this format](https://fairmut3x.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/cnf-conjunctive-normal-form-dimacs-format-explained/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file defines Boolean expressions written in Conjuctive Normal Form. Basically it’s clauses joined by AND, with each variable in the clause ORed together.

The first line of the file format (.cnf) starts with

```
p cnf num_variables num_clauses
```

So In your example 7 is the number of variables, 12 is the number of clauses.

Then each line defines a clause. For example:

```
(A v B v C) ^ (A v D v E) ^ (B v C v D)
```

number of variables is 5 (ABCDE), number of clauses is 3 (separated by AND)
The variable indexing starts from 1, wirh each clause on a seperate line. Each line ends with a 0 to signify end of the clause. To show a negation, add a “-“ (negative sign) before the variable.

```
p cnf 5 3
1 2 3 0
1 4 5 0
2 3 4 0
```

I don’t know what the e is in the first line.